# Logging customers in on the index.php

Tags: magento-1.9, login

Looking to log customers in based on a posted email address from a subdomain url. Should I be posting to a separate php file that contains

```
include_once "../app/Mage.php";
Mage::init();
$app = Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('4');

$email = $_POST['email'];
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId('4');
$customer->loadByEmail(trim($email));
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());

$app->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl() . '?SID=' . $custSessionId)->sendResponse();
```

Or should this code be utilized somewhere else (such as on the index.php)? How should I be logging in my customers from a remote site automatically?

Comment: Woah... So I can log in as any user by guessing their mail address. That's pretty bad from a security point of view. At least you should add a random token to every email and check if the token matches. index.php is not the right place for this, create your own module with a special controller for your functionality.

Comment: Not necessarily helpful as far as information goes but gives a sense of where I should be going.

Comment: That's why I added it as comment and not as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your actual question, no, you shouldn't use a standalone PHP file, nor should you use `index.php`. You should create a module with a controller that implements this logic. The external system should POST to your controller-action.

Now, to answer the question you didn't ask, *don't do this*. You're allowing anyone to log in as any one of your customers.

If you're looking to do an automated login, you need to implement some sort of handshake system. Have the external system generate a unique token that's associated to the email, send the pair to the target system, and then have the target system verify the token and email with the external system.

This way, you can only log in if you were authenticated on the external system. The tokens should be generated on a need-to basis, should be unique, should be one time use, and should expire quickly.